# Unintentional lag from when program executes .addSubview to when view actually appears- Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I am building a fairly simple iOS app that, when it boots up, loads a few views and stacks them on top of each other.

However I am experiencing a very long lag between when the app boots and when the views appear. These views are not complicated and take very little time to build.

At first I thought it might have been the image causing the delay, as I grab it via a URL. But after logging some checkpoints, the image load happens fairly quickly.

I did similar checkpoint logging when builidng the UIView and again, it's fast.

So finally, I checked to see if there was a gap between when the call to `.addSubview` is made and when the views actually appear, and in fact there is.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        let returned = feedMngr.retrieveFeed()

        if (returned) {
            self.constructFeedStack()
            self.view.addSubview(self.firstCardView!)
            self.view.insertSubview(self.secondCardView!, belowSubview: self.firstCardView!)
            self.view.insertSubview(self.thirdCardView!, belowSubview: self.secondCardView!)
            self.view.insertSubview(self.fourthCardView!, belowSubview: self.thirdCardView!)
            NSLog("fin")
        }
    }
```

After "fin" is logged (roughly 5 seconds after app launch), there is a 5-10 second lag before the views are actually presented.

Anyone know why this may be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the view hierarchy off of the main queue ("in the background"). This isn't allowed. Your UIKit calls all need to be on the main queue.

Comment: Ah I think that did it. Thank you!

Comment: Rob beat me to it. Note for future reference: When your UI code takes forever to render to the screen, acts strangely, or crashes when it shouldn't, it usually means you are trying to manipulate UIKit objects from a background thread. That's what I expected to find based on the subject of your question.